# Adding a project excluded from Source Control

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a solution with many projects in it (around 40). All these are under Source Control in TFS. What I want to do is to create a project in the same solution, but should be excluded from Source Control. I managed to do this from

File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control and unbound the project.

But the solution file which is under source control will still show changes.

I want these changes for this project in the solution file to be ignored.

How do I do it?

Comment: Why you want to do this ?

Comment: All projects in my solution are DLLs. I want to attach to a running process which I want to do in my project which will run and attach to process automatically.

Comment: Ya well. I have to add the .sln file to the .tfignore right? What exactly I want is, can I ignore the changes in the .sln file.?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using `.tfignore` file which could [Customize which files are ignored by version control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control)

This .tfignore file will not affect with those files already in source control. You need to manually delete/destroy the specific project first then check in the .tfignore file.

Besides, since all projects in your solution are dlls, source control dlls is not a recommend way. The easier and manageable way is using Nuget package to handle this. Create your custom nuget package in the server and [restore the package](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-installer)  during build pipeline. More details with Package Management in TFS, you could refer this [tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/overview).